# How do I access a Label object, given the TextBox bound its Content property?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, data-binding

My objective is to include the `Label`'s text in an error message if the content of the `Label`'s `TextBox` is not valid. During validation, when only the `TextBox` object is easily obtained, I would like to obtain the reference to the `Label` object which has had its `Target` property bound to that `TextBox`.

In other words, given the *source* of a binding, I would like to return or retrieve the *target* of that binding. The WPF `BindingOperations.GetBindingExpression()` and related methods require that the target object be known already.

In WPF XAML I have this:

```
<Label Target="{Binding ElementName=RatingTextBox}">_Rating:</Label>
<TextBox Name ="RatingTextBox"/>
```

In C# code-behind I tried this:

```
BindingExpression be = RatingTextBox.GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty);
string format = be.ParentBinding.StringFormat;
```

However, `be.ParentBinding` above is null even though my `TextBox` is definitely bound by the label because the hot key "[Alt]-R" works. Can my `TextBox` get that `Label`'s text somehow from the C# code-behind?

Comment: it may be a round-about way, but why not have a string property in your View Model and bind your label, textbox, and message box message to that single property?

Comment: are you using MVVM? Also, how are you checking that the content is invalid.add some sample code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you are looking for a way to automatically bind the `Tooltip` property of your `TextBox` to the `Content` property of whatever `Label` object the `TextBox` is a target of.

Unfortunately, to do this most easily would require a mechanism in WPF to, given the *source* of a binding, identify its target (or targets…a single source can be bound to multiple targets, of course). And as far as I know, no such mechanism exists as such.

However, I can think of at least a couple of different alternatives that should accomplish a similar effect:

1. When initializing the window, enumerate all the `Label` objects to find their targets, and update the targets' `Tooltip` properties accordingly. Either just set them explicitly, or bind the properties to the `Label.Content` property.
2. Reverse the direction the `Label` target is declared. I.e. create an attached property that can be used on the `TextBox` object, indicating which `Label` should target it. Then use this attached property to initialize the `Tooltip` property appropriate (e.g. in the attached property code, bind or set the `Tooltip` property, or have some other property that is also bound to the attached property and when it changes, handle the binding or setting there).

The motivation for using an attached property in the second option is to allow the label/target relationship to still be declared just once in the XAML (i.e. avoiding redundancy). It's just that the declaration occurs in the target object (i.e. the `TextBox`) instead of the label object.

Here are a couple of examples showing what I mean…

## First option above:

**XAML:**

```
<Window x:Class="TestSO32576181BindingGivenSource.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:l="clr-namespace:TestSO32576181BindingGivenSource"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
  <StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
      <Label x:Name="label1" Content="_Label:" Target="{Binding ElementName=textBox1}"/>
      <TextBox x:Name="textBox1"/>
    </StackPanel>
  </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

**C#:**

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        InitTooltips(this);
    }

    private void InitTooltips(FrameworkElement element)
    {
        foreach (FrameworkElement child in
            LogicalTreeHelper.GetChildren(element).OfType<FrameworkElement>())
        {
            Label label = child as Label;

            if (label != null)
            {
                BindingExpression bindingExpression =
                    BindingOperations.GetBindingExpression(label, Label.TargetProperty);

                if (bindingExpression != null)
                {
                    TextBox textBox =
                        FindName(bindingExpression.ParentBinding.ElementName) as TextBox;

                    if (textBox != null)
                    {
                        // You could just set the value, as here:
                        //textBox.ToolTip = label.Content;

                        // Or actually bind the value, as here:
                        Binding binding = new Binding();

                        binding.Source = label;
                        binding.Path = new PropertyPath("Content");
                        binding.Mode = BindingMode.OneWay;

                        BindingOperations.SetBinding(
                            textBox, TextBox.ToolTipProperty, binding);
                    }
                }
            }

            InitTooltips(child);
        }
    }
}
```

## Second option above:

**XAML:**

```
<Window x:Class="TestSO32576181BindingGivenSource.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:l="clr-namespace:TestSO32576181BindingGivenSource"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
  <StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
      <!-- Note that the Target property is _not_ bound in the Label element -->
      <Label x:Name="label1" Content="_Label:"/>
      <!-- Instead, it's specified here via the attached property: -->
      <TextBox x:Name="textBox1" l:TooltipHelper.TargetOf="{Binding ElementName=label1}"/>
    </StackPanel>
  </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

**C#:**

```
static class TooltipHelper
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty TargetOfProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("TargetOf", typeof(Label),
        typeof(TooltipHelper), new PropertyMetadata(null, _OnTargetOfChanged));

    public static void SetTargetOf(FrameworkElement target, Label labelElement)
    {
        target.SetValue(TargetOfProperty, labelElement);
    }

    public static Label GetTargetof(FrameworkElement target)
    {
        return (Label)target.GetValue(TargetOfProperty);
    }

    private static void _OnTargetOfChanged(
        DependencyObject target, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Label oldLabel = (Label)e.OldValue,
            newLabel = (Label)e.NewValue;

        if (oldLabel != null)
        {
            BindingOperations.ClearBinding(oldLabel, Label.TargetProperty);
            BindingOperations.ClearBinding(target, FrameworkElement.ToolTipProperty);
        }

        if (newLabel != null)
        {
            Binding binding = new Binding();

            binding.Source = newLabel;
            binding.Path = new PropertyPath("Content");
            binding.Mode = BindingMode.OneWay;

            BindingOperations.SetBinding(
                target, FrameworkElement.ToolTipProperty, binding);

            binding = new Binding();
            binding.Source = target;
            binding.Mode = BindingMode.OneWay;

            BindingOperations.SetBinding(
                newLabel, Label.TargetProperty, binding);
        }
    }
}
```

Note that in the second option, no new code is required in the window class. Its constructor can just call `InitializeComponent()` as usual and that's it. All of the code-behind winds up in the `TooltipHelper` class, which is referenced in the XAML itself.

Comment: Peter, your first option immediately worked and I like it. There is so much I don't understand about WPF data binding and you are clearing it up fast, thank you!